# Orientation In android?

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

I am new to Orientation in Android. I have worked only for `portrait` mode so far, now I am working for both orientations.
I am using this method in **manifest file** for orientation :---

```
        <activity android:name=".Activity_name"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

The Problem is :-

I have two layout Folders for this - one is `layout` &  other is `layout-land` for both orientations.
   Now I run my app sometimes it takes **layout xml file**  on both orientation & some times **layout xml file & layout-land xml file both works .**

**How to resolve this problem?**

& If i use this code :--

```
@Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        setContentView(R.layout.login_landscape);
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.login);         
    }
}
```

Then orientation problem gets resolved but Activity is not created again, so my code works only one time . My Button is not working now. 
2. My second question is that **For Both XML File How to manage Code in Config Method**
I want to know the complete concept of Orientation .
Answer will be highly Appreciated.

Thanks & Warm Regards,
Deepanker Chaudhary

Comment: i can help you in that case where for large or extra-large devices, your app will run in landscape mode and for small and normal devices, it will run in portrait mode?

Comment: can't you have different xml for different orientation and layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layout is same as layout-land for portrait orientation it is layout-port folder. There is no need for you handle the layout file for orientation changes. All you need is to save the data on orientation change and restore it when displaying it. You can use the same file name for both the orientations. You can get some help from [here](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/) for orientation handling. [check](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), also  [this](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/10/27/handling-orientation-change-in-android.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure below point :

> android:configChanges
>   Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.